# Cannot read interface property from a subclass that implements it?

Tags: c#, .net

Apologies if this is duplicate, I'm not familiar enough with the correct terminology to know if this is asked elsewhere. I'm new to interfaces and am creating some sample code to see what kind of helpful things they can achieve.

I have a method that returns two possible classes that both implement the same interface.  However, I can only access the properties from the parent class and not the sub-class, and have failed to find an explanation.  I realise my entire approach may be flawed and will accept that advise also.

This is better explained with an example ([NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XHfdHa)) and questions...

```
using System;

public interface IAb
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class A : IAb
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class B : A, IAb
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static class MyMethods
    {
        public static IAb CreateObject(Type t)
        {
            if (t == typeof(A))
            {
                return new A() {Prop1 = 123};
            }
            else
            {
                return new B() {Prop1 = 456, Prop2 = "Foo"};
            }
        }
    }

    public void Main()
    {

        IAb AorB = MyMethods.CreateObject(typeof(B));
        Console.WriteLine(AorB.Prop1);

        if (AorB is B)
        {

            // fails
            // Console.WriteLine((B)AorB.Prop2); // 'IAb' does not contain a definition for 'Prop2'

            // works
            B newVar = (B)AorB;
            Console.WriteLine(newVar.Prop2);

        }
    }
}
```

Based on the above:

1. Why does `AorB.Prop1` work, but not `AorB.Prop2` without an explicit cast?
2. Does the above mean that an interface should always be cast to a class before reading it's properties?
3. Is there a better way to specify the return type of the example method?  The current approach feels error-prone because this (albeit unlikely code)  would cause an error: `var AorB = (B) MyMethods.CreateObject(typeof(A));`

Comment: Specifying that `B` implements `IAb` is redundent, since it implements `A`, and `A` alread implements `IAb`. You can just do `public class B : A`

Comment: That's helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [pattern matching with `is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is) operator to make it more clear

```cs
IAb AorB = MyMethods.CreateObject(typeof(B));
Console.WriteLine(AorB.Prop1);
if (AorB is B b)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.Prop2);
}
```

Your failed line becomes correct after using right parenthesis

```cs
Console.WriteLine(((B)AorB).Prop2);
```

There is also no need to inherit `B` class from both `A` class and `IAB` interface. Since `A` already implements `IAB`, you can simply use `public class B : A`

> Is there a better way to specify the return type of the example
>   method?

Make the `CreateObject` method generic and use constraints to restrict `T` type parameter to class, which implements `IAb` interface and has a parameterless constructor (this's what `new()` means exactly)

```cs
public static T CreateObject<T>() where T : IAb, new()
{
    return new T { Prop1 = 123 };
}
```

and invoke it in the following way

```cs
IAb AorB = MyMethods.CreateObject<B>();
```

But in this case you can set only properties, defined in `IAb` interface, not the `B` class specific.

Comment: Great, thank you.  Is there any way to achieve access to `B` properties, or is that a limitation of interfaces and sub-classes?

Comment: @EvilDr if you call the method like `B AorB = MyMethods.CreateObject<B>();` and assign a result to variable of type `B`, you can see the `B` properties. But inside `CreateObject<T>` you can't assign them without cast, because compiler knows only that `T` contains `IAB` properties, not the underlying classes

Comment: Okay thanks, but `B.Prop2` cannot be set within `CreateObject<B>()`, correct?

Comment: @EvilDr nope, only properties of class/interface, which `T` restricted to, `IAB` in this case. You can have a look at [generic classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) and [generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) specs for details

Answer (score 2):

> Why does AorB.Prop1 work, but not AorB.Prop2 without an explicit cast?

Because the property selector has precedence over the type cast. Just add parentheses:

```
Console.WriteLine(((B)AorB).Prop2);
```

> Does the above mean that an interface should always be cast to a class before reading it's properties?

No.

> Is there a better way to specify the return type of the example method? The current approach feels error-prone because this (albeit unlikely code) would cause an error: var AorB = (B) MyMethods.CreateObject(typeof(A));

You could use generics:

```
T CreateObject<T>() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

However, that does not provide you with compile-time access to properties as in your example. You could slightly improve by providing versions of the method with appropriate constraints:

```
T CreateObject<T>() where T : IAb, new()
{
    var result = new T();
    result.Prop1 = 123;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful thank you.  Could you please clarify what `, new()` does in your code?  I've never seen that before.  Also, this last example doesn't provide access to `Prop2` - is that achievable at all using your approach?

Comment: It's a constraint that requires the type parameter to have a parameter-less constructor. Then you can create new instances of that type in the generic method.